# Python PyQt4 2 or more Commands in a .connect()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using Pyqt4 and I'm trying to make 2 commands work in one .connect()

What I have tried has failed me. Here is my code so far:

```
def startSreachBIT(self):
    self.Sreach = UISreach(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.Sreach)
    self.Sreach.B64BIT.clicked.connect(self.ButtonC1 + self.startUIToolTab)
    self.Sreach.B32BIT.clicked.connect(self.ButtonC12 + self.startUIToolTab)
    self.show()
```

Comment: Do you want the two slots to be called at the same time (i.e. call `self.ButtonC1()`, then `self.startUIToolTab()`). Or do you just want to call both slots separately, and in no particular order?

Comment: explain your question please

Answer (score 0):

you could have a function that calls both. for example:

```
def func(self):
    self.func1()
    self.func2()
def startSreachBIT(self):
   self.Sreach.B32BIT.clicked.connect(self.func)
```

if you want them to happen at the same time you could use threads but I recommend against.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is [QSignalMapper](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsignalmapper.html)